# How to use different themes to create a Tablet Application?

Tags: android, eclipse

So I have created a phone android app, but now I want to make it available for tablets.

You know the theme that phone apps have the gray bar on the top with the name of the app?
Well I want to make a tab app but with a theme like other app that also show the app logo.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a layout file with the same name of your layout and put it inside a folder named res/layout-xlarge/YOUR_LAYOUT_NAME.xml ... and change the design as you want but don't change the views' ids. By doing that the Android sdk will load that xml automatically on tablets and you don't have to change anything in your Java classes.
[See that link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)